# Is the continuous dual of a topological chain complex chain equivalent to the algebraic dual?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, homological-algebra, counterexamples

I apologize in advance if this is a naive question.

**Def:** A topological chain complex is a chain complex of topological $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces such that the boundary maps are continuous.

Let $C$ be a topological chain complex.

one can in a natural way consider the dual $C$* of the chain complex $C$ (ignoring the topology).

One can also consider the *continuous* dual of the topological chain complex $C^{*c}$  (because the boundary maps of $C$ are continuous)

Are $C$*, $C^{*c}$ chain equivalent? I would also like to know if the answer is yes after possibly adding some more conditions to ensure nothing pathological happens. For example, is the answer yes if one assumes further that all homologies of C are finite dimensional ?

Thank you,

Comment: I think that $C^{**}$ is a very dangerous choice of notation for a dual, whatever the flavour (as opposed to a double dual).

Comment: @LSpice  I agree. I will change it.

Comment: In general I don't think these will be equivalent even for a complex $d_1:E_2 \to E_1$ and $d_0: E_1\to 0$, if you take $d_1$ to have dense but non-closed range; for then the continuous dual of this complex is $d_0^* : 0 \to E_1^*$ and $d_1^* : E_1^* \to E_2^*$, whose cohomology in degree $1$ is $0$ since $d_1^*$ is injective

Comment: In general, they aren't chain equivalent. For, take a topological vector space $V$ such that the algebraic dual $V^\ast$ and the topological dual $V^{\ast c }$ aren't isomophic as vector spaces ($V=l^2$ is such an example) and take $C: 0 \to V \to 0$. Because chain equivalence induces an isomorphism on (co)homology, $C^\ast$ and $C^{\ast c}$ can't be chain equivalent.

Comment: @tj_ aha ,YemonChoi  aha, thanks for your comments. Do u think answer would be yes if the homologies of $C$ are required to be finite dimensional ?

Comment: Chain equivalence of chain complexes of vector spaces is equivalent to isomorphism of the homology groups. So, $C^\ast$ and $C^{\ast c}$ are chain equivalent iff $H_p(C^\ast) \cong H_p(C^{\ast c})$ for all p. But I don't know if this condition is forced by the finiteness of the dimension of the $H_p(C)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general they are not chain equivalent, even if $H_\ast(C)$ is finite dimensional. (I need the axiom of choice)

For a counterexample let $p \in (0,1)$ and let $f: L^p([0,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-zero linear functional. $W := \ker(f)$ is a topological space with the subspace topology and the inclusion $W \hookrightarrow L^p([0,1])$ is continuous. Take
$$C = (C_2 \to C_1 \to C_0):\qquad W \hookrightarrow L^p([0,1]) \to 0$$
Then $H_0(C)=H_2(C)=0, H_1(C)=\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $H_\ast(C)$ is finite dimensional.

By the Universal Coefficient Theorem, $H_1(C^\ast) \cong H_1(C)^\ast=\mathbb{R}$.

Denote the continuous dual by $(\,\, )'$. Then 
$$C': \qquad 0 \to L^p([0,1])' \to W' $$

Since $L^p([0,1])' = 0$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space), the complex is 
$$C': \qquad 0 \to 0 \to W'$$
and hence $H_1(C')=0 \not\cong H_1(C^\ast)$. Since chain equivalent complexes have isomorphic homology groups, $C^\ast$ and $C'$ are not chain equivalent.

**Remark:** One might ask, what $W'$ is. If I'm not mistaken, one can adopt the proof of the BLT theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension) to the metric of $L^p([0,1])$ and show that each continuous linear functional $W \to \mathbb{R}$ extends uniquely to a continuous linear functional $L^p([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$. This yields $W'=0$.